# Map function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary

As far as I understand map in Haskell takes a function and a List and applies that function to every element in that list before creating a new list with the function applied to each member.

Trying it out, this works fine with really simple functions like `(+5)` so it works fine if I type:

```
map (+7) [2,8,9,3]
```

I get:

```
[9,15,16,10]
```

However this doesn't work with functions that I have created. Say I have made a function `shiftLetter` whose type declaration is:

```
shiftLetter :: Char -> Int -> Char
```

(with Int shifting how far along the letter returned is)

If I make a new function to do it with more than one letter and type:

```
shiftLetters :: String -> Int -> Char
shiftLetters letters shift = map shiftLetters "AKHLKHN"
```

I get errors, why is this?

Comment: suppose that you've messed up `shiftLetters` and `shiftAlphabet`, check them again

Comment: What is `shiftAlphabet`? Something like `shiftAlphabet char = shiftLetter char shift` might be what you're looking for?

Comment: in the interpreter, do these things and figure it out on your own: `:t map`, `:t shiftLetter`.

Comment: and also `:t map shiftLetter "AKHLKHN"`, i mean.

Comment: Sorry I originally called the function a different name.

Comment: "I get errors, why is this?" because there *are* errors. And believe it or not, the text of the error messages is of concern, yes, indeed. If you do not read them, you should at least post them.

Comment: In `map shiftLetters "blah"` you almost certainly want to map `shiftLetter`, not `shiftLetters`. That's only one of the errors, though.

Comment: Note that the typespec for your shiftLetters function is probably wrong. If you map a function over a list you will get a list back, not an element of that list. You want "shiftLetters :: String -> Int -> String".

Comment: Sorry I copied it wrong the typespec for shiftLetter is: Char -> Int -> Char and shiftLetters: String -> Int -> String.

Answer (score 12):

If you check the type of the `map` function then you see:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

So you need a function that takes one parameter, but yours takes two. You have to use

```
shiftLetters letters shift = map (flip shiftLetter $ shift) letters
```

or

```
shiftLetters letters shift = map (`shiftLetter` shift) letters
```

Pointless style:

```
shiftLetters = flip $ map . flip shiftLetter
```

Comment: Okay thanks but I've never seen flip or $ before? What are they for?

Comment: or you can do `(\`shiftLetter\` shift)` instead of `(flip shiftLetter $ shift)`

Comment: The type system doesn't prevent you from mapping functions of more than one variable. (In fact, in the 'applicative' style it's very common.) `map shiftLetters` is a perfectly valid expression, with a type of `String -> [(Int -> Char)]`.

Comment: Trying this I get: Syntax error on 'shiftLetter'
    Perhaps you intended to use -XTemplateHaskell

Comment: @Eddie: The space after `$` is important.

Comment: I meant for Phil's function namely: ('shiftLetter' shift).

Comment: Also, what do I do if say shiftLetter(s) took more than 2 arguments? Say if shiftLetter type definition was: Char -> String -> Int -> Char and shiftLetters: String -> String -> Int -> String?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want

```
shiftLetters letters shift = map (`shiftLetter` letters) "AKHLKHN"
```

Comment: Because shiftLetters takes a String then an Int?

Comment: shiftLetter takes a Char, not a String. Note that String is the same as [Char] which is different from Char.

Comment: I know! Sorry the functions have very similar names. shiftLetter takes a Char but shiftLetters takes a String?